# Beautiful Soup - Getting top div tag without nested span

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags, find

I need to get just the top div tag without its nested tags.

```
<div class="listing-price">
    K75,000
    <span class="listing-price-sqm">$750000/m<sup>2</sup></span>
</div>
```

The code I have returns both the value from the div class tag and the span class tag :
`listing_price = house.find("div", class_="listing-price").text.strip()`

How can I get just the value  K75,000?

Thanks

Comment: could you try ```string``` instead of  ```text``` and  check it again. And also add output of your code to your question.

Comment: @iliya the output  is:                                                                                          
K75,000
    

    
        $750000/m2

Comment: did you remove ```strip()``` from from ```string```? Do it like this and report back.

Comment: I updated the code : listing_price = house.find("div", class_="listing-price").string but this time I do not get a value back. I have "None" as the result

Comment: could you give me the url so I have the chance to explore it for myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
soup.find('div', {'class': 'listing-price'}).get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contents` or `next_element` to get the value.

```
html='''<div class="listing-price">
    K75,000
    <span class="listing-price-sqm">$750000/m<sup>2</sup></span>
</div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one(".listing-price").contents[0].strip())
```

OR

```
print(soup.select_one(".listing-price").next_element.strip())
```

---

**OutPut:**

```
K75,000
```